# Exporting RSS feed list

Tags: rss, feed

I use Google for my RSS Reader and I want to export a list of all my feeds as a textfile to share with friends.  I find the Share function a bit limiting and with >200 feeds and some rarely updated I think that the Share feature is not sufficient.  My idea is to view page source and copy the relevant portions of the page:

```
,{id:"feed/http://feeds.feedburner.com/boingboing/iBag",title:"Boing Boing",categories:[],sortid:"0914F6C1",firstitemmsec:"1152886812555",htmlUrl:"http://www.boingboing.net"
```

And then use something like grep to remove the URLs and put in a list.  Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Click "Manage Subscriptions" then go to "Import/Export" and you can export them all as OPML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can export all of your feeds via OPML in the settings. Then load it up with a XMl lib and dump all the nodes to a text file or whatever format you want.